# How to disable selection of 1'st item in ComboBox that has same text as selected item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've tried to find solution for my problem and was unsuccessful,
so I would greatly appreciate any help.

I'm using `ComboBox` filled with Items (`Persons`).

**Setting ComboBox.DataSource:**

```
List<Person> lis_persons = new List<Person> {
    new Person {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Same",
        Surname = "Text",
        Address = "1'st Address"
    }, 
    new Person {
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Different",
        Surname = "Text",
        Address = "2'nd Address"
    }, 
    new Person {
        ID = 3,
        Name = "Same",
        Surname = "Text",
        Address = "3'rd Address"
    }
};

var lis_comboItems = lis_persons.Select(p => new {
    ID = p.ID,
    Person = String.Format(@"{0} {1}", p.Name, p.Surname),
    Address = p.Address
}).ToList();

CobPersons.DataSource = lis_comboItems;
```

**Person class:**

```
class Person {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**(EDIT) I've set:**

```
CobPersons.DisplayMember = "Person";
CobPersons.ValueMember = "ID";
CobPerson.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
CobPerson.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

As You can see it's possible that 2 different Persons have same Name and Surname.

`ComboBox` behaves like it should when user is scrolling/picking Person with focus on `ComboBox` (`SelectedValueChanged` is triggered as it should and `SelectedValue` has expected value).

When user changes/leaves focus Leave event is triggered as it should be and `SelectedValue` has expected value,
but right after that first Person with same Person(Text) value is selected (for no reason/by itself) and `SelectedValue` is changed to that Person's `ID`.

How to disable that behavior?
Is there any other way to "force Selection of Selected item" after `ComboBox` losing focus?

Comment: Why are you not using selectedindexchanged?

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged is triggered also, it doesn't make any difference which Event I'm using (I've used events just to check what's happening).

Problem occurs in ComboBox behavior that is changing SelectedItem by itself.

Comment: Exactly same code work fine form me. Check your code maybe you updating selected value somewhere. How you check selected value?

Comment: @Fabio I'm using this 2 events to test:

`private void CobPersons_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxbTest.Text = CobPersons.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }

        private void CobPersons_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TxbTest.Text = CobPersons.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }`

Comment: That mean `SelectedValueChanged` event was raised again after `Leave` event raised. Change happened again somewhere in the code

Comment: @Fabio Yes, that's what I wrote in 1'st post:  
When user changes/leaves focus Leave event is triggered as it should be and SelectedValue has expected value, but right after that first Person with same Person(Text) value is selected (for no reason/by itself) and SelectedValue is changed to that Person's ID.

Comment: The leave event should in no way trigger any changes imo. But since we don't know what is coded where we can't help you.

Comment: Show more code. For example where you initialize combobox `Load` eventhandler or `constructor of the form, or somewhere else

Comment: @TaW I never said that Event is causing this behavior.  It's an sample project (Form has ComboBox and TextBox, Creating lists and setting them as DataSource is in Form Constructor, I've provided EventHandlers in my previous comment).  There's no other code if You Copy-Paste it You should see same behaviour (When You pick 3'rd Person TextBox will say 3, but when You focus TextBox/ComboBox looses focus it'll say 1 because SelectedValue/Index/Item changed automatically).

Comment: [Same two items in combobox but first one always gets selected C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581471/same-two-items-in-combobox-but-first-one-always-gets-selected-c-sharp)